# passing multiple values as one value c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

if I have a struct:

```
struct v2 {
    int x, y;
}
```

I could use operator overloading to be able to do stuff like:

```
v2 v = {1, 2}, _v = {1, 1};
v = v + _v; // v = {2, 3};
```

but what do I do if I want to also be able to do stuff like:

```
v2 v = {1, 2};
v = v + {1, 1}; //v = {2, 3}
```

Comment: `v = v + v2({1, 1});`?

Comment: Imagine that you have another `struct w2 {double x, y}`. Then the symbol `{1, 1}` is ambiguous. You at least should tell the compiler it's a `v2`.